# About NSException from  "NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile :"

Tags: iphone, nskeyedarchiver

```
NSArray *t_annos;

@try 
{
  NSLog(@" --- pointer before = %ld --- ", (long) t_annos);  
  t_annos 
     = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile : d_path]; 
  NSLog(@" --- pointer after  = %ld --- ", (long) t_annos);
}
@catch (NSException *e) 
{
  NSLog(@" --- e caught  ---"); 
  t_annos = nil;     
}
```

Please consider the above statements, the situation is :

1

According to documentation,  an exception should be raised if d_path does not point to a valid archive.  But no exception is caught even if d_path is deliberately set with an invalid path.

2

Have tested the code on both the xcode simulator and a test devise (iphone).  Although both the simulator and the phone devise do not catch any exceptions, the phone unarchives the array as expected while on the simulator the program stops with an output : "Program received signal : "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"" at the Debugger Console.

3

The "bad access" error should have come at the "unarchiveObjectWithFile" statement since the program stops after the first NSLog output.

4

When try with a single NSString object archived and unarchive, both the simulator and the test device have no problem.  But there is still no exception caught even when the path is wrong.

There may be something missing on my part, hope that somebody knowledgable can help.

Comment: Please be a bit more creative with your titles. We know it's a question already.

Comment: What objects are in your array? Any custom class?

Comment: Objects in the array are from a custom class which conforms to NSCoding. So they (the objects) should be ok.

Comment: @mja, you are right. I should look more into the objects in the array.  Have made a minor error in defining the object's class.  Somehow the test phone is not affected but the simulator just stops at the coding error.  The problem is corrected and everything is ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, the exception is thrown only when there exists a file at the path and is not an archive created by `NSKeyedArchiver`.

> unarchiveObjectWithFile:
>
> Decodes and returns the object graph previously encoded by
>   NSKeyedArchiver written to the file at a given path.
>   + (id)unarchiveObjectWithFile:(NSString *)path
>
> Parameters: path
>
> A path to a file that contains an object graph previously encoded by
>   NSKeyedArchiver.
>
> Return Value
>
> The object graph previously encoded by NSKeyedArchiver written to the
>   file path. Returns nil if there is no file at path.
>
> Discussion
>
> This method raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if the file at path
>   does not contain a valid archive.

So, for -

1: Most likely the invalid path that you set is not pointing to any file, and hence the return value is nil without any exception.

2: Have you ensured the path on the simulator points to a valid file archived by `NSKeyedArchiver` earlier? Most likely, it points to some other file.

4: Same thing as #1.

Comment: I think you are right about "1".  As for 2, I think you could be right too but have yet found a good way to verify it thanks ...